# Using OpenMP to optimize this code on multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, openmp

I am having trouble optimizing this code. When attempting to put the for loops in parallel and use reductions and/or tiling and loop unrolling the code is having issues.

```c
void parallel_to_grayscale(long img[DIM_ROW][DIM_COL][DIM_RGB], long ***grayscale_img, long *min_max_gray) {
    int row, col, pixel, gray_pixel;
    int min_gray = 256;
    int max_gray = -1;

    #pragma omp parallel for private(row, gray_pixel, pixel)
    for (col = 0; col < DIM_COL; col++) {
        for (row = 0; row < DIM_ROW; row++){
            for (gray_pixel = 0; gray_pixel < DIM_RGB; gray_pixel++) {
                for (pixel = 0; pixel < DIM_RGB; pixel++) {
                    grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel] += img[row][col][pixel];
                }
                grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel] /= 3;
                if (grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel] < min_gray) {
                    min_max_gray[0] = grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel];
                    min_gray = grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel];
                }
                if (grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel] > max_gray) {
                    min_max_gray[1] = grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel];
                    max_gray = grayscale_img[row][col][gray_pixel];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried other optimization techniques but this is the reference code. We are expecting this code to convert an image to grayscale

Comment: Instead of declaring a bunch of loop variables `private`, declare them in the loop header. That's even better style regardless OpenMP,

Comment: "having issues" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Flattening your arrays might be helpful. All these layers of indirection can be very costly. Depending on the way these "multidimensional arrays" are allocated you also could have cache locality issues at the moment.

Comment: For correctness, you certainly need `reduction(min: min_gray) reduction(max: max_gray)`. Instead of doing redundant reductions on `min_max_gray`, I would just assign them at the end of the function from `min_gray` and `max_gray`.

Comment: While one can guess realistic values of `DIM_*`, the exact values are relevant to optimizing this code, so you should add them to the question. Ideally you would also add the hardware you are using and the number of threads that you are trying to use (environment variables?).

Comment: At the moment, only the outermost loop is parallelized. Depending on the DIM_* values, collapsing (`collapse(3)`) the loops might help to gain more concurrency. To declare the variables in the loop header, you might need to pass `-std=c99` to the compiler. Running a data race detection tool on the code would highlight you the issue mentioned by @paleonix. `clang -fopenmp -fsanitize=thread -g` should give you the report. Adding the reductions is still the right fix.

Comment: @Joachim provided that `DIM_COL` is large enough (which probably is the case) there's littlt gain to expect by collapsing the loops. It may even hit the performances if the workload per iteration gets too low, and one should take into considerations that many compilers do not efficiently implement `collapse`